# Jquery: is there a and selector?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code where I have a click event on a `<tr>`. This event should not trigger when I click on a specific `<td>`. The code that I have now does this just great, but now I want to add one more condition where the event on the `<tr>` should not trigger when it's clicked.

I want to add a `<span></span>` which, if clicked, does trigger the event on the `<tr>`.

Here is my code:

```
// Change background color on rows in new candidates list
$(".newCandidatesTableTr td:not(#testTD) span:not(#candidateID)").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("diffColor");
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("diffColor", this.clicked);
});
```

This doesn't work:

```
span:not(#candidateID)
```

How should I do this?

Comment: I'd recommend using event delegation for managing complex click events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably select the top-most elements that can be clickable, then filter away click events on the more specific elements that should not be clickable.

```
$('tr.newCandidatesTableTr > td').click(function (e) {
    // Get a jQuery-wrapped instance of the clicked element.
    var target = $(e.target);
    // Filter clicked element (due to bubbling, this is not necessarily the <td>
    // element.)
    if (target.is('td#testTD') || target.is('span#candidateID')) {
        // Pass on event.
        return true;
    }

    // Do stuff...
});
```

Comment: Also have a look at jQuery's `live` function which can improve performance a lot if you have many `<td>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Change background color on rows in new candidates list
$(".newCandidatesTableTr td[id!=testTD] span[id!=candidateID]").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("diffColor");
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("diffColor", this.clicked);
});
```